# Why is my code going to the next line? (Java)

Tags: java

I have a piece of code like so:

`System.out.printf("%s %s earns $%,.2f%n a year", employee3.getFirstName(), employee3.getLastName(), employee3.getWeeklyPay()*52);`

Which should print out:

"Harry Harris earns $45,000 a year"

but instead comes out like

"Harry Harris earns $45,000

a year"

with the text going down to the next line. Whats going on here?

Comment: What does it do instead?

Comment: What are your inputs and what is the result?

Comment: Remove your ```%n``` code

Comment: What does [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#dls) say about what `%n` does?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `"%s %s earns $%,.2f a year"`

`%n` outputs a line break.

Answer (score 0):

As Antaaaa said, do not write `%n`.
I would also suggest to use MessageFormat, it is much simpler.

```java
import java.text.MessageFormat;

System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("I'm using Java {0}! It came out in {1}", 14, 2020));
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html